# How do I import a dataframe as a reactive value?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to create a dataframe where I can import my own data, then add additional rows if need be. This code can take a dataframe and add rows to it, but is missing an input file.

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("a", "a", 1),
  actionButton("add", "add"),
  tableOutput("sum")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactiveVal(tibble(col = numeric(0)))
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    dat(tibble::add_row(dat(), col = input$a))  
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderTable(dat())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So when I try to convert this code into one that can take an input dataframe I write

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ion2<-reactive({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    ions<-read_xlsx(file$datapath, sheet=2)
    
    return(ions)
  })
  
  
  dat <- reactiveVal(tibble(col1=ion2()[1]))
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    dat(tibble::add_row(dat(), col = input$a))  
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderTable(dat())
  
}
```

I get the error  `You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.`

I've tried many different things but there doesn't seem like there is a way to import a file and then have it be a reactive value later. I can't seem to find a way to import a file, then add rows to that file. If anyone could give me some help that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With `dat <- reactiveVal(tibble(col1=ion2()[1]))` you are calling the reactive Value "ion2()" outside a reactive Environment. You can put the expression in an observe() like this:

```
observe( dat <- reactiveVal(tibble(col1=ion2()[1])) )
```

(Look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/observe.html for reference)

Alternatively you can also intialize your reactiveVal at the start of your server function and assign it a value directly after loading the file:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- reactiveVal()
  observe({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    ions<-read_xlsx(file$datapath, sheet=2)
    
    dat(ions)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    dat(tibble::add_row(dat(), col = input$a))  
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderTable(dat())
  
}
```